# How to get Image path from Image component, for those images that are dragged and dropped in authoring

Tags: adobe, aem, aem-6

Am having a requirement on the image path of the images that are dragged and dropped in AEM author mode. I tried with String imageAssetSrc =  image.getFileReference() in the JSP, but this is taking the path where the image is uploaded. Is it possible to the complete image path after the image is dragged and dropped.

Comment: Can you please provide me an ex: for 'image is uploaded' , ' complete image' paths?

Comment: "in the jsp"? What AEM version are you working with?

Comment: Am using AEM6.4 
After drag and drop am getting image path as below.
/digital/assets/_jcr_content/par/panel_container_1/par/image_5.img.jpg/1571117404201.jpg
Am using the default image component from AEM.

Comment: Yes it is a JSP. Image component

Comment: do you want where the image got uploaded to? or the local path from where you dragged the image from?

Comment: Need to know where the image path is uploaded